# Due in next 90 days filter in a data view

Tags: filter, data-view-web-part

I'm making data views and for a couple of them I want to filter to show any items that are due within the next x amount of days.  My immediate thought was to filter by Current Date + 90.  I've done this with calculated fields before, but it doesn't work in a data view filter.  Is there a parameter I can add to somehow make this work?  Or some other way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by creating a calculated field that I named DueInNinety.  The calculation was `=[Due Date]-90`.  Then I created a filter on my view to show items where `Due Date >= Today` and `DueInNinety <= Today`.